# Issue with JS form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a simple form, I am trying to use javascript to validate the from but I cant get it to work and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using the same code to validate a form on another project and that works but for some reason the code wont work with another form.

Here is the code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
    if(document.contactForm.email.value===""){ 
    alert("Please provide a valid email");
    document.contactForm.email.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>

    <form name="contactForm" method="POST" id="contactForm" onsubmit="return(validate()">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="name" id="name" class="fields" type="text" placeholder="name"></td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="email" class="fields" type="email" placeholder="email"></td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="phone" class="fields" type="phone" placeholder="phone(optional)"></td>            
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><textarea name="message" class="fieldsMessage" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea></td>            
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input class="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: you are missing a right parenthesis in your `onsubmit="return(validate()"`

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was going to be something I simply overlooked. Always the simple things huh.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<input type="email" name="email" required="required" />
```

html5 will automatic validate it for you.
or you can use this

```
$("document").ready();

function checkForm(formObj){
$("#table td>span").remove();
        var msg="";
        for (var i=0; i < formObj.elements.length; i++) {
               // check if the form element has a validate attribute. 
               if (formObj.elements[i].name !=null && 
                 formObj.elements[i].getAttribute("validate")){
                 var validationRule = 
                   eval(formObj.elements[i].getAttribute("validate"));
                   if (!validationRule.test(formObj.elements[i].value)||formObj.elements[i].value==""){ 
                    var obj = formObj.elements[i].parentNode; 
                   // add a !!! mark on the validate field 
                    if (obj.nodeName=="TD")
            var dialog = formObj.elements[i].getAttribute("validateMsg")+"\n";
            msg +=  dialog;
                     obj.innerHTML = 
                       obj.innerHTML +"<span style='color:red; font-size:12px;' >"+ dialog +"</span>"; 
                   }//--> end test regExp
                 }//--> end if element has validate attribute
                }// end loop through the form elements. 
               if (msg.length > 0){
                 return false;
               }
                 else{
                  return true;
                 }
            }//--> end function
```

html form:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);" name="frm">
  <table width="430px" id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" validatemsg="please enter your name" validate="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="email" validatemsg="PLease enter email"
        validate="/^([\w]+)(.[\w]+)*@([\w]+)(.[\w]{2,3}){1,2}$/" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="subject" validatemsg="plaese enter the subject" validate="/^[a-zA-Z1-9 ]*$/" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is your main issue...

```
<form name="contactForm" method="POST" id="contactForm" onsubmit="return(validate()">
```

should be

```
<form name="contactForm" method="POST" id="contactForm" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Additionally, you may want to set email value to "" like this...

```
<input name="email" class="fields" type="email" placeholder="email" value="">
```

because validating email.value==="" might not return true otherwise